# post data to a django view from angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I have an existing views.py file in my django app something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def segment_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = segment_form()
    else:
        if form.is_valid():
            info = request.POST['info_name']
            output = script_function(info)
            return render(request, 'your_app/your_template.html', {
            'output': output,
      })
    return render(request, 'your_app/your_template.html', {
    'form': form,
  })

def script_function(info):
    '''here goes my main logic'''
    x=y=w=h=102

    return x,y,w,h
```

which used to interact with a django template and a django form.But, now i am in the process of shifting everything to a angular frontend app so i replaced the form with a angular $http post.

**index.html**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="image in images track by image.pk">
                <h3>
                    Image {{ image.pk }}
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="deleteImage(image)">Delete</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="segmentImage(image)">Segment</button>
                </h3>
                <a href="{{ image.image }}">
                    <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ image.image }}">
                </a>
            </div>
```

**app.js**

```
...
$scope.segmentImage = function(image)
    {
    $http({method:'POST', url:'127.0.0.1:8000/image/segment_image/', data:{'image': image}})
        .then(function successCallback(response)
        {
            console.log('success')
        },function errorCallback(response)
        {
            console.log('failed')
            console.log(response.config)
            console.log(response.statusText)
        }
    )};
...
```

Now what changes do i need to make to my views.py so that it can recieve the image from angularapp and pass it to my script_function, and render the return values(x,y,w,h) back to index.html

Comment: need to call` script_function `directly?

Comment: none of my logic goes to segment_image function so i can either directly call script_function or call it from segment_image.

Comment: created a url for script_function?

Comment: no i havent created any url for script_function

Comment: create one and use this library to send images https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

Comment: No I have an existing implementation to upload images and display them to the user.now I am extending this to process these images.so I want to just pass this stored image to my python script to process it.

Comment: in that case just pass the image id to the script_function.and get image from the db or cloud and process it.

Comment: @zabusa can you be more elaborate and point me to right resources for my problem